# Reseting variables and editing arrays with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm building an app using AngularJS and LocalStorage. I've run into a problem that it's a tad too complex for me.

I have a list of people, and the idea is to be able to add arrays of names. I choose X names, click add, creates an object in an array, it **resets the list**, and I can start over, choose X names, click add, etc.

Here's how I create the temporary array that then I push into LocalStorage:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="staff in stafflist | orderBy: 'name'">
    <button class="btn form-control" ng-show="!staff.chosen" ng-click="pushStaff(staff)">{{staff.name}}</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" ng-show="staff.chosen" ng-click="unpushStaff(staff)">{{staff.name}}</button>
  </div>
  <button class="btn ng-click="addRecord()">Add passangers</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.paxlist = [];
$scope.pushStaff = function (staff) {
    staff.chosen = true;
    $scope.paxlist.push(staff);
    console.log($scope.paxlist);
};

$scope.unpushStaff = function (staff) {
    staff.chosen = false;

    var index=$scope.paxlist.indexOf(staff)
    $scope.paxlist.splice(index,1);     
    console.log($scope.paxlist);
}
```

My problem is that I can create objects into the array, but **when I add an object, the selected items of the list of names won't reset**, so they will be pre-selected when adding the next object. 
At the same time, it will also stay linked to the last object added, so when I modify the selection, the last object will also get modified.

This also messes with the possibility of adding an editing capability for each object of the array.

I've created a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KuGqQYNoZ2hxq2pIGwaU?p=preview) that illustrates the issue.

If you could shed some light on the issue, that would be brilliant.

Comment: As I understood you want to achieve something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/vV8OuKiTKYkFyy7SrjOS?p=preview

Comment: That resets it perfectly! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it. About editing capabilities, how would you compare the full name´s list with the names of each object? Something like: I click on edit, the names from the object turn blue in the main list, I can edit them, and save again? I guess that's a hassle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `addRecord` you need reset property `chosen`

```
$scope.addRecord = function () {
    $scope.recordlist.push({ pax: angular.copy($scope.paxlist) });

    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);

    $scope.editItem = false;
    $scope.paxlist  = [];

    $scope.stafflist.forEach(function (el) {
      el.chosen = false;
    });
};
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vV8OuKiTKYkFyy7SrjOS?p=preview